# PHP with JSON decode and steam api

Tags: php, json, api, decode, steam

I am new to php at this stage, same about openID libraries. I want to make a website for Steam users so I need to display their inventory. I've downloaded some example things which most thing written but I still need something else. As a training I took a something else than inventory, but similiar. Didn't make it so I hope that you can help me.

That's a example what I was looking at while trying to decode another data.

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76hidden",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1
        }
    ]

}
```

}

And code in PHP looks like

```
$url2 = file_get_contents("url");
$content = json_decode($url2, true);
$_SESSION['steam_steamid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];
$steamprofile['steamid'] = $_SESSION['steam_steamid'];
```

And this one above is working well. Could you please explain me why there is 0 between "steamid" and "players"? Also it looks like the session name matters, am I right? I was doing some tests and when I changed the name session it didn't work.

So here's what I am working on
JSON code:

```
{
    "friendslist": {
        "friends": [
            {
                "steamid": "765hidden",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1428495026
            },
            {
                "steamid": "764hidden",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1355599210
            },
            {
                "steamid": "764hidden",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1423504205
            },
            much more friends
        ]

    }
}
```

So I want to get the steamid and I got no idea how to get it. I've tried to get relationship as steamID is already used above:

```
$url3 = file_get_contents("url2");
$content2 = json_decode($url3, true);
$_SESSION['steam_relationship'] = $content2['friendslist']['friends'][0]['relationship'];
$steamfriends['friend'] = $_SESSION['steam_relationship'];
```

And of course echo $steamfriend['friend'] is not working. I see that person who made these PHP files already know what are the session names (if they need to be right to work). Any ideas where can I find it?

I feel really ashamed that I can't figure it myself.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The first JSON

```
{
  "response": {
    "players": [
      {
        "communityvisibilitystate": 3, 
        "profilestate": 1, 
        "steamid": "76hidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

translates to this PHP array

```
$content = array(
    "response" => array(
        "players" => array(
            array(
                "communityvisibilitystate" => 3,
                "profilestate" => 1, 
                "steamid" => "76hidden"             
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The players is an array of arrays (hash arrays), so to access the first player you need to use index number (`$content["response"]["players"][0]["steamid"]`) even if there is just one player in the players array.

To get all `steamid`s from the second array, you just need to run a simple foreach:

```
$friendIds = array();
foreach ($content2["friendslists"]["friends"] as $friend) {
    $friendIds[] = $friend["steamid"];
}
# array("764hidden", "764hidden", "764hidden")
var_export($friendIds);
```

Comment: It's the same thing like with "content". There's nothing more. I just can't figure how to get steamid from friends list. The first one was an example made by some programmer and I can't do same thing but with other variables. That's all

tl;dr - get steamid one of friends just like I got steamid of "players" which was one so there was only one steamid. Now there are severals (because there are many friends).

Comment: @user3898922 If I get it right, you want to get steamid of all players in the response to an array?

Comment: Edited. Is there anything specific you want to do with the array of friends or friend ids?

Answer (score 0):

When the JSON is created they use a method similar to this:

```
foreach ($record as $response){
  $content['response']['players'][] = $response;
}
```

Where $player may be an array with multiple values, or not.

It just makes it easier to create the JSON.

First make the JSON an array:

```
$array = json_decode($json,true)
```

Then get it like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['relationship'] = $array['friendslist']['friends'][0]['relationship'];
$_SESSION['steamid'] = $array['friendslist']['friends'][0]['steamid'];
$_SESSION['steam_relationship'] = $array['friendslist']['friends'][0]['steam_relationship'];
```

The typical way to get all the player info:

```
foreach ($array['friendslist']['friends'] as $key => $value){

  $steamid = $value['steamid'];
  $relationship = $value['relationship'];
  $friend_since = $value['friend_since'];

        // do what need to be done here.

}
```

Comment: Can you explain me the thing about sessions? When I changed it from $session_steamid to $sessios_steam and used it like should (about echo and other things) it just didn't work. So the session name is important, right?

Comment: I've been doing this a long time and have never had a good reason to use a SESSION variable.  Better would be to ask how to do what you want to do with the SESSION

Comment: You need to do a `session_start()` first before saving the variables.